# How can i use await if i am hard coding the data instead of using query

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, oauth-2.0, async-await, owin

I am overriding the two methods of *OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider* but i am hardcoding the data as you seen below . how can i use await ? and where can i apply there so compile can build it

```
    public class MyAutorization : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            context.Validated();
        }
        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            if (context.UserName == "admin" && context.Password == "admin")
            {
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin"));
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("username", "admin"));
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Mulla"));
                context.Validated(identity);
            }
            else if (context.UserName == "user" && context.Password == "user")
            {
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "user"));
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("username", "user"));
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Boland"));
                context.Validated(identity);
            }
            else
            {
                context.SetError("Access Denied", "Invalid User Name And Password");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can remove the `async` keyword and add `return Task.CompletedTask` or `Task.FromResult(0)` for older framework versions

Comment: @JSteward can edit the above code in the old version

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: @JSteward it does work for me , thankyou for the help

Comment: Task.FromResult(0) did my work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is necessary to use await wheneveryou write async , but with old aproach you can do this .

```
public class MyAutorization : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
        {
            public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
            {
                context.Validated();
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
            public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
            {
              //  await Task.CompletedTask
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
                if (context.UserName == "admin" && context.Password == "admin")
                {
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin"));
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim("username", "admin"));
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Mulla"));
                    context.Validated(identity);
                }
                else if (context.UserName == "user" && context.Password == "user")
                {
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "user"));
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim("username", "user"));
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Boland"));
                    context.Validated(identity);
                }
                else
                {
                    context.SetError("Access Denied", "Invalid User Name And Password");
                }
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        }
```